# Running Java Program in Sub-Directory

Tags: java, unix, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

Please give suggestions if my formatting is wrong, this is my first time posting a question here.  Using UNIX, I'm having trouble running a Java program 'Master' (located in a sub-directory) from the top-level directory.  Compiling works just fine from the top-level, but I can't actually run the java code from the top-level.  I think I may be misunderstanding classpath / the classpath flag.  My directory structure is like so: /top-level/src/amsPassageretriever.

When I try to run everything from the top-level directory, I get the following error:

```
user:~/top-level$ javac -classpath :/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/lucene-core-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/contrib/wordnet/lucene-wordnet-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lemur/latest/share/indri/indri.jar src/amsPassageretriever/*.java
user:~/top-level$ java -classpath :/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/lucene-core-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/contrib/wordnet/lucene-wordnet-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lemur/latest/share/indri/indri.jar src/amsPassageretriever/Master
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: src/amsPassageretriever/Master (wrong name: amsPassageretriever/Master)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: src/amsPassageretriever/Master.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `java` is not a file, it is the fully qualified classname of a class inside the classpath (the main class that you want to execute).

It sounds like like class you want is `amsPassageretriever.Master` (I am assuming you made a typo calling the package `amsPassageretrieve` at the end of your post).

Hence you should invoke:

```
java -classpath :/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/lucene-core-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/contrib/wordnet/lucene-wordnet-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lemur/latest/share/indri/indri.jar amsPassageretriever.Master
```

**Update:**
If you want it to run properly when you are not in `src` then you need to add that directory to your classpath too:

```
java -classpath /home/user/top-level/src:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/lucene-core-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lucene/latest/contrib/wordnet/lucene-wordnet-3.1.0.jar:/NLP_TOOLS/info_retrieval/lemur/latest/share/indri/indri.jar amsPassageretriever.Master
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I did make a typo. I edited my post to better structure the question.  I tried running your command line from /top-level but I still get the same error.  I tried various permutations with intermediary /src folder in there (src/amsPassageretriever.Master or src.amsPassageretriever.Master) but no dice.

Comment: Yes, just spotted that your `src` directory is not in your classpath. Update posted.

Comment: Awesome, I just tried it with your update and it works.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, you might want to consider putting your compiler output in a different directory to your source. If you do, then you will need to change the classpath to point to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

try `java amsPassageretrieve.Master` as amsPassageretrieve is the package as far as i can see

you may also need to add classpath variables if your class requires

Answer (score 0):

You are typing "retrieve" and "retriever" which are two different words