# "NoClassDefFoundError" when running JUnit 4 from Cygwin terminal

Tags: java, junit, cygwin, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

Earlier, I downloaded `junit-4.12.jar` and `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` and added them to my Windows `CLASSPATH`. When I want to run a JUnit test, I open the Cygwin terminal, navigate to the directory of my test class, and run

```
$ java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestClass
```

or, if I'm not in the correct directory, I type the relative file path to the class separated by `\` (I've read that this is necessary on Windows, even using Cygwin, when running `java` or `javac`).

I compiled the test class from `TestClass.java`, which has been provided by someone else. The test is supposed to initially throw `testThrowsIllegalArgumentException()`, but I am instead receiving `NoClassDefFoundError`–as if the program somehow failed before the actual testing itself–followed by a stacktrace:

```
JUnit version 4.12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: proj/TestClass (wrong name: TestClass)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        ...
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
```

(There is more stack trace in between, which I have removed to conserve space because the only internal steps that seemed important to me were the beginning and end. I can edit the post to include the full stack trace if necessary, though.)

I have looked at every other FAQ and StackExchange thread that I think is relevant without finding an answer to my problem. Right now, it seems that it may have to do with `CLASSPATH`. I've tried adding the directories of the test class and the original class that it's testing using `java -cp`, but like everything else, it hasn't worked. Any further help would be appreciated, because I'm completely at a loss right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much experimentation, I have finally solved my own problem.

My project directory had initially been intended for Eclipse (I decided early on that I'd rather not install Eclipse if I could help it, which is probably why I had this problem in the first place). It is structured like so:

```
proj  
| src  
| | main  
| | | java  
| | | | proj  
| | | | | Class.java  
| | | | | Class.class  
| | | | | [other java files]  
| | test  
| | | java  
| | | | proj  
| | | | | TestClass.java  
| | | | | TestClass.class  
| | | | | [other java test files]  
| [other directories]
```

Additionally, the files `Class.java` and `TestClass.java` both have the statement `package proj;` at the beginning. Apparently this means that after compiling, for example, `TestClass`, I needed to refer to it as `proj.TestClass` *from the parent directory* when calling `java` in the terminal.

If I'd been paying more attention to the error message, I would have seen that `java` was specifically expecting `proj/TestClass`. From this [answer to a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5944020/10946717):

> The argument to `java` is not a file, it is the fully qualified classname of a class inside the classpath (the main class that you want to execute).

The Cygwin commands that ended up working:

```
$ cd proj/src
$ java -cp "$CLASSPATH;main\java;test\java" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore proj.TestClass
```

Since I'm ultimately still using Windows, `java` is a Windows command, so the argument to -cp needed to be formatted as a Windows-style path list.

My `CLASSPATH` on Windows: `.;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.12.jar;%JUNIT_HOME%\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar`